# Adding arguments into component throws an error

Tags: angular, components

I have a simple `component`  like this:

```
import { Component, Optional  } from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
      selector: 'error-handler',
      templateUrl: './error-handler.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./error-handler.component.css']
    })
    export class ErrorHandlerComponent  {

        constructor(@Optional() private error?: any) { }

    }
```

and when I go to browser I get an error:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for ErrorHandlerComponent: (?).
```

I have register my new `component` in module so I don't know why this error occures. I don't call the constructor from anywhere yet.

What is the way to provide arguments into contructor of the `component`?

Comment: when you add an argument inside your constructor, you make sure there is an instance in that type to provide it, you can't  add an argument of type 'any' inside the constructor!!

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. Can you provide some example?

Comment: Angular take the responsibility to instantiate  the component, in other words, angular will call the constructor, in order to call the constructor, you need to provide its arguments, now angular read the arguments type and try to provide them, the type of the argument is critical, you need to make sure that this type can be provided.

Comment: in other words you should create a provider for the component that create an instance with parameter passed into the constructor, it doesn't matter what parameter type is used.

Comment: Are you able to show me the code how to fix it?

Comment: The fix for your code would be to remove that whole `@Optional() private error?: any`.  I think the bigger question is "Why do you need to sometimes pass in an error?"  You should never be calling `new ErrorHandlerComponent(error)` (if it is a component, it should *always* be instantiated by angular).  So if you need an error to get in there, you should probably do it as an `@Input() error: any;` before the constructor